# Peek inmplementation for linked list in rust

Tags: rust, linked-list, singly-linked-list

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=693594655ea355b40e2175542c653879

I want `peek()` to remove the last element of the list, returning `data`. What am I missing?

```
type Link<T> = Option<Box<Node<T>>>;

struct Node<T> {
    pub data: T,
    pub next: Link<T>,
}

struct List<T> {
    pub head: Link<T>,
}

impl<T> List<T> {
    fn peek(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
        let mut node = &self.head;

        while let Some(cur_node) = &mut node {
            if cur_node.next.is_some() {
                node = &cur_node.next;
                continue;
            }
        }
        let last = node.unwrap();
        let last = last.data;
        return Some(last);
    }
}

#[test]
fn peek_test() {
    let mut q = List::new();
    q.push(1);
    q.push(2);
    q.push(3);

    assert_eq!(q.empty(), false);
    assert_eq!(q.peek().unwrap(), 1);
    assert_eq!(q.peek().unwrap(), 2);
    assert_eq!(q.peek().unwrap(), 3);
    assert_eq!(q.empty(), true);
}
```

To save the `head`, I need to access the elements by reference, but the puzzle does not fit in my head. I looked at "too-many-lists", but the value is simply returned by reference, and I would like to remove the tail element.

Comment: Aside: The name `peek` is usually associated with returning the value of a colletcion without removing it, I'd strongly recommend using something like `pop`/`pop_end` instead.

Comment: You can't mutate through a shared reference (unless behind a `UnsafeCell` which you don't need) period. You probably want to call `Option::take` somewhere in your `peek`

Comment: @cafce25 If I use `take`, then I lose the `head`. Or should I rebuild the list again by going through the nodes? I have already implemented the `pop` method, there are no problems with it. It's just that a minimal example is provided in the code, rust is pretty verbose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this work you have to switch from taking a shared reference (`&`) to a mutable one.

This results in borrow checker errors with your code wihch is why I had to change the `while let` loop into one
which checks if the next element is `Some` and only then borrows node's content mutably and advances it.

At last I `Option::take` that last element and return it's data. I use `Option::map` to avoid having to `unwrap` which would panic for empty lists anyways if you wanted to keep your variant you should replace `unwrap` with the try operator `?`.

So in short you can implement a `pop_back` like this:

```rust
    pub fn pop_back(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
        let mut node = &mut self.head;
        while node.as_ref().map(|n| n.next.is_some()).unwrap_or_default() {
            node = &mut node.as_mut().unwrap().next;
        }
        node.take().map(|last| last.data)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest something like below, Just because I spent time on it .-)

```
fn peek(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
        
        match &self.head { 
            None => return None,
            Some(v) => 
                if v.next.is_none() {
                    let last = self.head.take();
                    let last = last.unwrap().data;
                    return Some(last);
                }
        }
        
        let mut current = &mut self.head;
        loop {
            match current {
                None => return None,
                Some(node) if node.next.is_some() && match &node.next { None => false, Some(v) => v.next.is_none()} => {
                    let last = node.next.take();
                    let last = last.unwrap().data;
                    return Some(last);
                },
                Some(node) => {
                    current = &mut node.next;
                }
            }
        }
       
    }
```